# Undefined '$qrcode' variable in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code

I'm working on a Laravel project about how to generate a QR Code with a hashed information. However, when I call the variable from my blade file, it says 'Undefined variable $qrcode'. May I get some help?

This is how my Controller (PostController) looks like:

```
public function index()
{
    $post = Post::all();
    return view('blog.index', compact('post'));
}

public function create()
{
    return view('blog.create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post;
    $post->randomnumber =  random_int(100000, 999999);       
    $post->user_id = Auth::id();
    $post->unit = $request->input('unit');
    $post->guestname = $request->input('guestname');
    $post->guestphone = $request->input('guestphone');
    $post->guestemail = $request->input('guestemail');
    $post->guestic = $request->input('guestic');
    $post->guestcarplate = $request->input('guestcarplate');
    $post->numberofguests = $request->input('numberofguests');
    $post->date = $request->input('date');
    $post->time = $request->input('time');
    $post->hash = Hash::make($post->randomnumber);
    $post->save();
    return view('blog.qrcode');     
    
}


public function generate ($id)
{     
    $post = Post::findOrfail($id);        
    $qrcode = QrCode::size(300)->generate($post->hash);
    return view('blog.qrcode', compact('qrcode'));        
}
```

This is how my Route looks like:

```
Route::get('posts/create', 'PostController@create')- 
>middleware('auth');   

Route::post('posts', 'PostController@store');

Route::get('/qrcode/{id}', 'PostController@generate');
```

And this is how my blade file (qrcode.blade.php) looks like:

```
@extends('layouts.frontend')

@section('content')

                <h4>
                    QR Code                        
                </h4>

                 {{ $qrcode }} 
            
@endsection
```

Comment: This line looks like it shouldn't work: `$post = Post::findOrfail($id);`. Where is `$id` defined? Do you have another route that returns that `blog.qrcode` view where you're not including `compact('qrcode')`?

Comment: @TimLewis their `store` method returns that view with no data ... also the fun times of returning a view instead of a redirect from a processing action [assuming that store method should redirect to the 'generate' action]

Comment: @lagbox Ah right, good catch (it's Monday, isn't it?). And yeah, in my experience, there are very few times it is a good idea to return a `view()` from a `POST` request. @pijin Your code will work better if you return a redirect to `generate` after your `store` method, and add an ID parameter to that Route so that `$id` is actually defined.

Comment: @TimLewis, didn't notice that `$id` before. I guess its because I followed others' coding. No, I don't have another route that return that `blog.qrcode`.

Comment: Yeah, my first comment is a bit off; you're never hitting that line of code since your `store` method returns the `return view('blog.qrcode');` with no data (as lagbox said). Follow the comments above and you should be able to get this working 

Comment: @TimLewis to be clear, I just need to change `return view('blog.qrcode');` in `store` method to `return redirect('blog.qrcode');` ?

Comment: No, you don't have a Route called `blog.qrcode`. You're redirecting to your `generate` Controller action, which is handled by `Route::get('qrcode')`. But, you need to add a URL parameter for `$id` to work. Please follow along in the Documentation for how to do all of that.

Comment: Redirects: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#creating-redirects, Route Parameters: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Alright, thank you so much @TimLewis

Comment: No problem! If you run into any more issues, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70337734/edit) with your new code and we can help further then 

Comment: @TimLewis sure will do!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Laravel is absolutely right. Because after creating the post, you are returning to the `view('blog.qrcode')` but you have not mentioned what is $qrcode. That is why it is throwing the error.  I can't understand your motive. What do you want to after creating the post? Do you want to display the qr code?
If so, At first assign some name to this route like this,  Name can be anything as your wish.

`Route::get('/qrcode/{id}', 'PostController@generate')->name('generate-qrcode');`

Then in your controller `store()` method replace
`return view('blog.qrcode');`  this line with this line `return redirect()->route('generate-qrcode');`. It will redirect to the qr code page.  if your motive is something else. let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code, it seems that the `$qrcode` variable is only defined and passed to the view in the `generate` function of your `PostController`. However, the blade file you shared (`qrcode.blade.php`) doesn't seem to be calling the `generate` function to generate the QR code.

To fix this issue, you can modify the `qrcode.blade.php` file to include a link that calls the `generate` function of the `PostController` to generate the QR code. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
@extends('layouts.frontend')

@section('content')

<h4>
    QR Code
</h4>

<img src="{{ route('qrcode.generate', $post->id) }}" alt="QR Code">

@endsection
```

In this modified blade file, we replaced the `{{ $qrcode }}` variable with an `img` tag that points to the `generate` function route of the `PostController` using the `route` helper function. We also passed the post id as a parameter to the route.

Make sure to update your `web.php` file to include a named route for the `generate` function:

```
Route::get('/qrcode/{id}', 'PostController@generate')->name('qrcode.generate');
```

After this modification, when you access the `qrcode.blade.php` file, it should display the QR code generated by the `generate` function of the `PostController`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it but it still doesn't work out